# Can't fix small error on the GoogleDrive Android API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have imported everything, compiled all the files in gradle, and implemented methods correctly. But, I can not get this code to work! I keep getting one compile error after compilation. This is my code:

```
package com.example.googleapi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GDriveLogin();

    }

    void GDriveLogin(){

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

this is the error I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: It would help to see your gradle file.

Comment: I face the same issue when I add: compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'     or when I add compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.5.3'

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error appears when you pass 65,000 methods. By adding all those libraries you are probably passing that [limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

If this is the case, try multidexing by adding:

`multiDexEnabled true` under `defaultConfig` in your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

It is a WILD GUESS, but I think you can try to fix it by replacing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-...
```

in your app module's '*build.gradle*' (basically, pull only selected subset of GooPlaySvcs).

As I said, it is a long shot and I don't know what subsets your app needs.

Good Luck.